# NVPROF Error: unable to locate profiling library libcuinj64.so

Tags: cuda, clang

I have already tried some answers from AskUbuntu, but none helped. The "missing" library can be found by the locate command:

```
$ locate libcuinj64.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/libcuinj64.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuinj64.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuinj64.so.7.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuinj64.so.7.5.18
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/doc/man/man7/libcuinj64.so.7
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcuinj64.so
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcuinj64.so.8.0
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcuinj64.so.8.0.61
/usr/share/man/man7/libcuinj64.so.7
/usr/share/man/man7/libcuinj64.so.7.gz
```

I have also exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/bruno/install/clang/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

And, tried the LD_PRELOAD trick, then it says that libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39 can't be found, but:

```
$ locate libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39
/usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39
/usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.39
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did try reversing the clang and cuda libraries in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, putting CUDA first?

Comment: Tried with no success. It works well when I LD_PRELOAD both libraries.

Comment: Did you set up a link /usr/local/cuda ?  The install is to /usr/local/cuda-8.0.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local | grep cuda`
`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Abr 13 00:04 cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-8.0`
`drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Abr 13 00:04 cuda-8.0`

Comment: Did you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH from wherever you set it up (.profile?)